# File storage in Spring

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, spring-mvc

I would like to save files uploaded from a form to certain folder in my Spring 3 application. I'm a rookie with this, don't know how to get started. Files must be java File format.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can define the absolute path to a temporary directory using [System Properties and Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based):

```
<!-- package shortened for readability -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework....CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="uploadTempDir"
      value="#{ systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir'] }/yourwebapp/upload"/>
</bean>
```

**Reference:**

- [System Properties and Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based)
- [System.getProperties()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) (includes reference for `java.io.tmpdir`)

Comment: I should get the path of my applications webContent Folder

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring's FileUpload support, [it's fully documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart), with examples.

Comment: I tried to set <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="uploadTempDir" value="files"/>
    </bean> Files are folder in my WebContent, but the file still goes TomCat's bin folder

Comment: @mjgirl: That's because you're giving it a relative directory path. Give it an absolute path.

Comment: Do you mean c:/myNetbeansInstallationFolder/ProjectFfolder etc? How's that gonna work when the application is in Internet?

Comment: @mjgirl: It needs an absolute path to a directory that's present in however you've deployed (relative filename resolution in Java is... generally confusing and best avoided).

Comment: see my answer for getting an absolute path